# Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:3.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Здравствуйте! При сборке проекта в Android Studio возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:3.0.0:.
         Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.jar
```

Предоставляю коды из build.gradle файлов. В 'Module: app':

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        dependencies {
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.one.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.4'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Код В 'Project: one':

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

На всякий случай скрин из SDK Manager:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как устранить ошибку? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Наверное вы забыли `google-services.json` в `app` модуль положить.

Comment: Можно поконкретнее пожалуйста.

Comment: У вас подключена либа для рекламы. Она от `Firebase`. А всё, что связано с `Firebase` требует скачивания из его консоли файла, помянутого выше, который надо копирнуть в проект.

Comment: А может вам надо вот это добавить в файл сборки уровня проекта рядом с `jcenter()` - `maven {url 'https://maven.google.com'}`

Comment: maven {url 'https://maven.google.com' не помог

Comment: А добавление файла, следовательно, помогло?

Comment: Если честно со скачиванием файла не особо понял, подключена для рекламы

Comment: Вам надо пойти на сайт `Firebase`. Создать там проект. В проекте создать приложение для андроид. Вбить туда хэши ключей, коими подписывается приложение. После этого сайт предложит вам скачать файл, указанный выше.

Comment: Вот видео где можно добавить рекламу admob проще с самой Android studio https://youtu.be/IFI59umsats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас нет файла `google-services.json`. Инструкция по его генерации есть в последнем пункте (Шаг 6) [этой статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/316528/).